# USB drive doesn't unmount

Tags: 10.10, usb, usb-drive, nautilus-elementary, unmount

When I unmount usb in nautilus elementary(using unmount button) sidebar it restarts rather than unmounting !

Comment: It's more a bug than a question, maybe this is not the right place for this kind of topics.

Comment: Nautilus elementary often hangs when unmounting volume and AFAIk this is a known bug.

Comment: There is no activity for this question for a long time and none of the answers seem to be good enough to consider them a solution, this was flagged for deletion as abandoned. If you feel that this issue still affects you and you would like to see a solution for it please drop a comment or open a thicket so a moderator can re open it.

Answer (score 1):

You can also run this command from the terminal.  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below.

```
umount /path/to/usb/drive/
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

**Right click** on your USB Drive and select "*Safely Remove Drive*"

Answer (score 0):

You can try **ejecter**. A small gnome panel applet which shows you mounted volumes and safely unmount it.